# swift and python api connection

Tags: python, ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create an IOS app using SwiftUI that will entail users entering in information and then that information being entered into an SQL database. I have my sql database on a Amazon RDS and created an app that can make changes and interact with the database.

My question now is how do I get my SwiftUI user input to connect to that python app? I was thinking it would be something like I would pass in the user input into a function that the python has to write the data to the database. **But I have no clue how to link the two (swiftUI and python)**, thats the main issue. Any help?

I haven't tried anything yet, I have seen a couple things that I have to host my python api publicly and then connect my swift ui to it kinda how I connect my python app to my database using an IP Address but I didn't know if there was other options.

Comment: I don’t work with Python but don’t limit your search to SwiftUI. SwiftUI is a UI framework any solution of interfacing between Swift (an language) and Python would not have any bearing with the UI.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to create an API in your python backend. Use something like FastAPI. Make REST API calls from swiftui to your python backend to pass in data to store.